# Basis, transition matrices and coordinate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Let $V=P_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Let $B={1,t,t^2}$ be the standard basis of $V$ and consider the ordered set $B1={1+t,t+t^2,1+t^2}$ of $V$.
>    Question 1) Prove $B1$ is a basis of $V$.
>    Question 2) Determine the transition matrix from $B$ to $B1$ and $B1$ to $B$.
>    Question 3) Let $v=1+2t+3t^2$. Determine the coordinate vectors $[v]_B$ and $[v]_{B1}$.

I have done question 2 but really don't know where to start with question 1.

For question 3 I have written $v$ in terms of $B_1$ to get $[v]_{B1}$ but not sure how to work out $[v]_B$ from this? I'm not sure if I'm missing a trick or something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> consider the ordered set B1={1+t,t+t^2,1+t^2} of V.
>    Question 1) Prove B1 is a basis of V.
>
> I have done question 2 but really don't know where to start with question 1.

You need to check two things:

1. Is $B_1$ a linearly independent set?
2. Does $B_1$ span $V$, i.e. can every polynomial of degree two be written as a linear combination of the elements of $B_1$?

If the answer to the first question is 'yes', then you could skip the second one if you know that the dimension of $P_2\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ is equal to 3; and if you are allowed to use this of course. If not, there is still the manual approach and this will involve solving a linear system (3 by 3).

> Question 2) Determine the transition matrix from B to B1 and B1 to B.
>    Question 3) Let v=1+2t+3t^2. Determine the coordinate vectors [v]B and [v}B1.
>
> For question 3 I have written v in terms of B1 to get [v]B1 but not sure how to work out [v]B from this? I'm not sure if I'm missing a trick or something!

The 'manual approach' would be to write $1+2t+3t^2$ as a linear combination of the elements of $B_1$ (use unknown coefficients) and solve this system of three linear equations in the three unknown coefficients.

But since you set up the transition matrices in question 2, you can of course use this result!

---

Addition after comment.

To check whether $1+t$, $t+t^2$ and $1+t^2$ are linearly independent, you look at the following system of equations:
$$a \left( 1+t \right) + b \left(t+t^2 \right) + c \left( 1+t^2 \right) = 0 \iff
\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
a+c & = & 0 \\
a+b & = & 0 \\
b+c & = & 0 
\end{array}\right.$$
They are linearly independent if the only solution to this system is the trivial zero solution (so $a=b=c=0$).

Comment: Great thanks, ive managed to do question 3 now. Still a bit stuck on question 1 though, I'm not sure how to show whether B1 is linearly independent or not!

Comment: @Jones I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Oh yes of course I understand that now! Is that all you need to show in order for B1 to be a basis of V? Or do you need to show that B1 is a spanning set for V? If so, how?!

Comment: @Jones You need both: linearly independent (see point 1 in my answer) and spanning (see point 2 in my answer; with instruction on how to check this).

Comment: I've shown that B1 spans V with numerous examples, but is there a more generic way of proving this? @StackTD

Comment: @Jones Yes, you show that you can make an _arbitrary_ polynomial (e.g. $at^2+bt+c$) of degree 2. Showing it for one or more examples, is insufficient.